# Where should be the '.\format' folder

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks, post-commit-hook

I have been getting the error message "VisualSVNServerHooks: Can't open file 'C:\Arquivos\format'" when I perform a commit to VisualSVN server. There is no any folder named "format" on the VisualSVN folder. Where it should be? Why it is been required if it was not installed with VisualSVN server ( free version )?

Thanks a lot.

Jayme.

Answer (score 2):

Jayme,

Looks like there is a mistake in the post-commit hook code.

As I see, your hook script looks for the 'format' file in the
repositories root. A 'format' file is a part of Subversion repository and has to be in the repository folder. I assume that *'C:\Arquivos\'* is the repositories
root and is not a repository itself. The correct path to repository in your case should be *'C:\Arquivos\repository-name\'*.

You can provide us with the hook to check the details.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. "C:\Arquivos de Programas App32\SVN" is the base instalation folder. The repository folder is "C:\Arquivos de Programas App32\SVN\Sul\Aplicacoes", where there is a "hooks" folder and also a "format" file.
`code`"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
commit-notification "%1" -r %2 ^
--from svnserver@traduzclara.com.br --to jjeffman@cpovo.net ^
--smtp-server smtp.traduzclara.com.br ^
--smtp-port 25 ^
--smtp-user uuuuuuuuu@uuuuuuuuu.uuuuu ^
--smtp-password *************
`code`
The code above was made using VisualSVN Server Manager.

Comment: Ok, I have got it to work some time ago thank you very much.